# Why uploading file with tomahawk is not working?

Tags: jsf, file-upload

I have an Icefaces 3.x + JSF 2.1 app where I tried to integrate upload file solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5424229/174349) but I receive

> 14:31:24,506 WARN 
>   [org.apache.myfaces.custom.fileupload.HtmlFileUploadRenderer]
>   (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) t:inputFileUpload requires
>   **ExtensionsFilter** or **TomahawkFacesContextFactory** configured to handle
>   multipart file upload, and any of them has been detected. Please read
>   the instructions on
>   http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/extensionsFilter.html for more
>   information about how to setup your environment correctly. Please be
>   sure ExtensionsFilter is the top most filter if you are using multiple
>   jsf libraries. 14:31:24,507 WARN 
>   [org.apache.myfaces.custom.fileupload.HtmlFileUploadRenderer]
>   (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) **t:inputFileUpload requires the
>   current request be intercepted by the filter** in order to handle forms
>   with multipart encode type. ExtensionsFilter was initialized but the
>   current request was not intercepted. Please add a filter-mapping entry
>   to intercept jsf page requests.

which is pretty strange because I added:

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

into my web.xml but still the uploaded file is null.

Any clue to what I do wrong?

Comment: Because ICEfaces which has builtin file upload parser has already parsed/consumed the request beforehand. ICEfaces documentation is lacking, so I can't tell how to disable it. Related read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008943/icefaces-seam-file-upload-component-not-uploading-files/13051355#13051355 Can't you just use ICEfaces own file upload component?

Comment: Thanks @BalusC. Unfortunately I have issues with their component (spent days on that issue already): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216829/why-acefileentry-does-not-work and seems that their devs are not so helpful: http://www.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/22360.page#sthash.wa4a777e.dpbs